# "Жизненно()важный"

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

Слитно или раздельно пишется слово "жизненно()важный" (орган)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Жизненно важный* — совосочетание, а не слово. Так что писать его следует раздельно.